# hide a div in 1 page that comes from the master page

Tags: asp.net, css, html, master-pages

i have a site, and made a master page.

this master page shows the footer for 10 pages which are all the same.

However i want one page not to show the footer.

how do i do this?

if i delete the div of the footer, then all the footer are deleted, how do i only delete it from one page. any ideas?

with each master page it comes with header and footer, so i cant disconnect the master page of the site.

is there any css i cane use or anything.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a CSS`(display:none)` to a specific page for which you want to hide.

Assuming `myFooter` is the ID of your footer div

***PageWithNoFooter.aspx***

```
<style type="text/css">
#myFooter
{
 display:none;
}

</style>
```